# AssertionError on RuleTester for ESlint rule

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, eslint

I have written a custom ESLint rule for a NodeJS application. The rule works as expected. However, I am facing issue running Unit test on my custom rule.

I have followed ESlint's documentation for writing [RuleTester](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/nodejs-api#ruletester) which is a **Mocha** unit test case in essence. Given below is my test case code.

```
const { RuleTester } = require("eslint");
const rule = require("../../../lib/rules/chai-expect");

const ruleTester = new RuleTester();
ruleTester.run("chai-expect", rule, {
  valid: [
    {
      code: "chai.expect(result).to.have.status(200);"
    }
  ],
  invalid: [
    {
      code: "expect(result).to.have.status(200);",
      errors: [
        {
          message: "chai.expect() should be used for assertions in test cases."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      code: "result.should.have.status(200);",
      errors: [
        {
          message: "chai.expect() should be used for assertions in test cases."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      code: "should(result).have.status(200);",
      errors: [
        {
          message: "chai.expect() should be used for assertions in test cases."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

I have provided one scenario for **valid** and three scenarios for **invalid** cases. Test case works fine for valid case. For invalid case I get the following error for all three scenarios.

> ```
> 1) chai-expect
>       invalid
>         expect(result).to.have.status(200):
>
>  AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Should have 1 error but had 0: []
>  + expected - actual
>
>  -0
>  +1
>
>  at testInvalidTemplate (/node_modules/eslint/lib/testers/rule->tester.js:468:24)
>  at Context.RuleTester.it (/node_modules/eslint/lib/testers/rule->tester.js:584:25)
> ```

I have debugged this error and found this block in the ESLint library throwing error.

```
assert.strictEqual(
    messages.length, item.errors.length,
    util.format(
        "Should have %d error%s but had %d: %s",
        item.errors.length, item.errors.length === 1 ? "" : "s", messages.length, util.inspect(messages)
    )
);
```

**item** represents an object from **invalid** block in test case. I can't figure out what **messages** represents here. I get a blank array for its value.

Comment: I presume `messages` are the reported error messages... ESLint doesn't seem to think you had any in your case. If present, I expect they would be `LintMessage` objects: https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/nodejs-api#%E2%97%86-lintmessage-type